# Recursive Function Error or Too difficult to compute?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have created three functions that are suppose to calculate this polynomial:

`(c[0]+T*(c[1]+T*(c[2]+T*(c[3]+T*(c[4]+T*(c[5]+T*(c[6]+T*(c[7]+T*(c[8]+T*(c[9]))))))))))`

This First Function calculates this polynomial using hardcored values

```
double poly(double Temp)
{
    double T = Temp;
    double p = (c[0]+T*(c[1]+T*(c[2]+T*(c[3]+T*(c[4]+T*(c[5]+T*(c[6]+T*(c[7]+T*(c[8]+T*(c[9]))))))))))
    return p;
}
```

This Second function calculates this polynomial iteratively

```
double poly2(double Temp)
{
    double T = Temp;
    double p = 1;
    for(int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(i < 9)
        {
            p*= T;
            p+=c[i];
        }
        else
        {
            p*=c[9];
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

This Third function calculates this polynomial recursively

```
double poly3(double Temp, int i, double p)
{
    double T = Temp;
    double p1 = p;
    if(i == 9)
    {
        p1*=c[9];
        poly3(Temp,i-1, p1);
    }
    else if(i < 9 | i > 0){
        p1*=T;
        p1+=c[i];
        poly3(Temp,i-1, p1);
    }
    else if(i == 0)
    {
        p1*=T;
        p1+=c[0];
        return p1;
    }

}
```

MAIN

```
int main() {
    cout << std::setprecision(15) << poly(15) << endl;
    cout << std::setprecision(15) << poly2(15) << endl;
    cout << std::setprecision(15) << poly3(15, 9, 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The Problem is that the first two functions return the exact same result but the 3rd function causes the compiler to time-out. I have been thinking through the logic but I just can't figure it out. I don't know if there is an error or it just takes too long to compute but if you see an error can you please help me solve it. Thank you very much!

[Ideone Compiler Example](http://ideone.com/FCuCmp)

Comment: "causes the compiler to time-out.” I think you didn’t mean that.

Comment: @RishavKundu I should correct myself the ide gave "Time limit exceeded" warning

Comment: Do you perhaps want a `||` and not a `|`?

Comment: You're not returning anything from the first two `if` blocks.

Comment: @MattCremeens I alway forget which is,  binary or logical operator

Comment: @IrrationalPerson ... but that's not because of compile time taking too long, but **running** your program triggers that actually.

Comment: @Barmar WOW you just found the answer Thanks!

Comment: I should have replaced | with && :( dumb mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems:

1. If you want to test whether a number is between two values, you need to **and** the comparisons, not **or** them.
2. The logical operators are `||` and `&&`.
3. You're not returning anything when you perform the recursive calls. You need to combine the result of that call with the current value.

```c++
double poly3(double Temp, int i, double p)
{
    double T = Temp;
    double p1 = p;
    if(i == 9)
    {
        p1*=c[9];
        return poly3(Temp,i-1, p1);
    }
    else if(i < 9 && i > 0){
        p1*=T;
        p1+=c[i];
        return poly3(Temp,i-1, p1);
    }
    else if(i == 0)
    {
        p1*=T;
        p1+=c[0];
        return p1;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is necessary for that return statement  p1 + poly3(Temp, i-1, p1) ?

Comment: I think so -- how else will you combine the result of the recursive call with the current element?

Comment: It might actually need to multiply, not add. The formula is confusing.

Comment: *= and += are used to "add" to the p1 and when i is 0 it returns p1

Comment: Oh, I see. You're using `p` as the accumulator. I'll update.

Comment: I don't need to return anything in those if and else if statement  because the final result is already stored inside p1 which is added to till i = 0 in which it is returned

Comment: You need to return *something*. Otherwise, the result of the recursive call is just thrown away. It needs to propagate back up through all the calls.

Comment: That's one of the most common mistakes we see when people post questions about recursive functions.

Comment: I don't return anything in those if statement because p1's value is carried across through the function parameter and is returned when the else if parameter is satisfied.

Comment: But the `if` isn't satisfied until you get to a deeply nested call. It returns the final result, and that needs to be returned back up to the original caller.

Comment: I took the liberty of testing my solution which doesn't use return statements in the first two if statements and yours and it turns out both of our solution returns the same value. The return statements don't really matter in this case because with or without them the code still gives the correct answer

Comment: It's working by accident. If a function that is defined with a return type doesn't use `return <expression>`, the behavior is undefined. It just so happens that it's returning the value from the last function called before it fell off the bottom. But this isn't defined by the C++ language.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Take a look at this variation: http://ideone.com/pdo2Uo It simply prints a blank line after performing the recursive call, and this makes the whole thing fail.